Increasing Tripplet Subsequence
I was attempting the Increasing Triplet Subsequence problem on leetcode.com
I started off with a brute force approach but it ran into time out issues but passing almost all testcases. The following is the code:
public static void main(String[] args) {
        IncreasingTriplet it = new IncreasingTriplet();
        int[] nums = { 1, 5, 0, 4, 1, 3 };
        System.out.println(it.increasingTriplet(nums));
    }

    public boolean increasingTriplet(int[] nums) {
        // if there are less than 3 numbers return false;
        if (nums.length < 3)
            return false;
        return helper(nums, nums.length, Integer.MIN_VALUE, 0, 0);
    }

    private boolean helper(int[] nums, int n, int prev, int index, int count) {
        if (index >= n) {
            if (count < 3) {
                return false;
            } else if (count == 3) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } else if (count == 3) {
            return true;
        } else if (count > 3) {
            return false;
        }
        if (nums[index] > prev) {
            if (helper(nums, n, nums[index], index + 1, count + 1) || helper(nums, n, prev, index + 1, count)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return helper(nums, n, prev, index + 1, count);

I then saw a pattern and decided to store the result of whether the "index" in question was part of an increasing tripplet sequence as the 1st, 2nd or 3rd number in the sequence.
This means I woukld need to create a cache that tracks each index in either 0, 1,2 poistions cache[][] = new int[nums.length][3]. I don't pass all testcases. Can anyone provide some guidance as to whether this approach is wrong? Any advise is appreicated.
The Code with caching is below:
public boolean increasingTriplet(int[] nums) {
        //if there are less than 3 numbers return false;
        if(nums.length < 3) return false;
        int[][]cache = new int[nums.length][4];
        for(int i = 0; i < cache.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < cache[0].length; j++){
                cache[i][j] = -1;
            }
        }
        return helper(nums, nums.length, Integer.MIN_VALUE, 0, 0, cache);
    }
    //Let's optimize by keeping track of the index as either part of the sequence as 1st, 2nd or 3rd and then store that for future use.
    private boolean helper(int[] nums, int n, int prev, int index, int count, int[][]cache){
        if(index >= n){
            if(count < 3){
                return false;
            }
            if( count == 3){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        if(count == 3){
            return true;
        }
        if(count > 3){
            return false;
        }
        if(cache[index][count] != -1){
            return cache[index][count] == 1? true:false;
        }
        if(nums[index] > prev){
            if(helper(nums, n, nums[index], index + 1, count + 1, cache) || helper(nums, n, prev, index + 1, count, cache)){
                cache[index][count] = 1;
                return true;
            }
            cache[index][count] = 0;
            return false;
        }
        return helper(nums, n, prev, index + 1, count, cache);
    }


Related: Increasing Triplet Subsequence

You do not need dynamic programming. Instead, you can just check every index as a possible middle index, i.e. it has a value smaller than it to the left of it in the array and a value larger than it to the right of its index in the array.
These can both be precomputed in linear time by tracking the smallest value so far while iterating forwards, then maintaining the largest value while iterating backwards.
public boolean increasingTriplet(int[] nums) {
    var hasLess = new boolean[nums.length];
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
        hasLess[i] = min < nums[i];
        min = Math.min(min, nums[i]);
    }
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (hasLess[i] && max > nums[i]) return true;
        max = Math.max(max, nums[i]);
    }
    return false;
}

Note that this can also be solved with O(1) extra space.

thanks but is there a possible way to do it with dynamic programming or optimizing what I have because the recursive nature and the fact that it can be broken down into subproblems lead me to take that route.....your solution is obviously fantatic but it will help be better if I can hone my skills going from brute force to optimized.

@Spindoctor You're getting a wrong answer after memoization because you missed the prev part of your state. But the number of possible states is way too large, so this approach is untenable. Optimizing a solution often involves considering different approaches, so it's best not to get stuck on one idea.

Could you help me understand please. Prev is the previous number. Are you suggesting adding prev to the cache but as the previous index instead ie., cache[index][seq][prevIndex]?

@Spindoctor Yes, that is the idea. However, that will still be too slow due to the very large number of states.

Dynamic programming is simpler and faster than this. It doesn't have to be complicated. Really. See my answer.

@btilly I suppose you could classify that as dynamic programming, but it's more of a greedy approach. And I'm aware of that solution (see the last line of my answer).

@Unmitigated Dynamic programming is the fancy name for "we save a previously seen answer to avoid recomputing work". Top down is just adding a caching layer to recursion to memoize. Bottom up is that we save some state as we go along that contains all the information that we might ever need again. In this case the state happens to be really simple - what's the best first and second value we found already in a rising sequence?

The tradeoff is that top down is usually easier to write, while bottom up takes more thought but we can throw away information that we will never need again. I've never found any of the lectures about subproblems to be at all helpful in thinking about this.

@Unmitigated BTW the last line of your answer looked to me to be a reference to taking a max and min on the fly as you went through the array. Trading off space for time, but keeping the idea of checking each in turn to see if it is a the middle. Which is not how I did it.

@btilly In any case, that was the solution I was referring to, which I agree is an elegant one (a simpler case of longest increasing subsequence in linearithmic time). I originally wrote this method as I believed it would be easier to understand.

Here is a fast solution in Python. Translation should be easy.
def has_increasing_triplet (array):
    first = second = max(array) + 1
    for v in array:
        if v <= first:
            first = v
        elif v <= second:
            second = v
        else:
            return True
    return False

The logic is simple. first is the smallest thing so far encountered. second is the smallest thing that, when encountered, was larger than first. So an increasing sequence of two. And if we ever encounter something bigger than second, that's the third in an increasing triplet.
This is O(1) memory and O(n) work. And yes, this does qualify as dynamic programming.

I decided to offer an explanation of how to get to this from applying the ideas of dynamic programming to a straightforward solution.  All code will be untested.
First, write the most straightforward code that you can, which always looks backwards from where you are in the array. Like this.
def has_increasing_triplet (array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        # Is array[i] the third in a triplet?
        for j in range(i):
            if array[j] < array[i]:
                # is array[j] the second in a triplet?
                for k in range(j):
                    if array[k] < array[j]:
                        # Found it.
                        return True
    return False

Now remember. The key idea in dynamic programming is, "Save the result of previous calculations to avoid repeating work." We don't, for example, need to keep trying to figure out if array[10] is the second in a triplet. It is or it isn't. So we can calculate it once and we are done.
def has_increasing_triplet (array):
    seconds = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        # Might have to check array[i-1] for being a second.
        if 0 < i:
            j = i-1
            for k in range(j):
                if array[k] < array[j]:
                    seconds.append(array[j])
                    break # Don't need to look more.
        
        for j in range(len(seconds)):
            if seconds[j] < array[i]:
                return True

But hey, it doesn't matter whether we add the new value that might be there before checking if array[i] is a third, or after. And doing it after saves us some bookkeeping.
def has_increasing_triplet (array):
    seconds = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        for j in range(len(seconds)):
            if seconds[j] < array[i]:
                return True

        for k in range(i):
            if array[k] < array[i]:
                seconds.append(array[i])
                break # Don't need to look more.
    return False

Now it is very common when we get to this point that we say to ourselves, "Hey, do I need all of these values? Can I just keep the best ones?"
Here it is clear. If you just keep the smallest value in seconds, there is no need to look through that array! And so now...
def has_increasing_triplet (array):
    second = None # This is more idiomatic Python.
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if second is not None and second < array[i]:
            return True

        if second is None or array[i] < second:
            for k in range(i):
                if array[k] < array[i]:
                    second = array[i]
                    break
    return False

And now we can do all the same refactors with the first in the triplet. This gives us:
def has_increasing_triplet (array):
    first = None
    second = None

    for i in range(len(array)):
        if second is not None and second < array[i]:
            return True

        if second is None or array[i] < second:
            if first is not None and first < array[i]:
                second = array[i]

        if first is None or array[i] < first:
            first = array[i]

    return False

And from here it is just code golf. We can get rid of the various None checks by just using a large number. Above I used a sum. But let's be less hacky.
import math

def has_increasing_triplet (array):
    first = second = math.inf

    for i in range(len(array)):
        if second < array[i]:
            return True

        if array[i] < second and first < array[i]:
            second = array[i]

        if array[i] < first:
            first = array[i]

    return False

And then we realize that if we're setting first, we cannot be setting second. There is a tricky edge case about matching the previous value. But if you look carefully we can get it as well with a well-placed <=. And so we get this:
import math

def has_increasing_triplet (array):
    first = second = math.inf
    for v in array:
        if v <= first:
            first = v
        elif v <= second:
            second = v
        else:
            return True
    return False

Except for the code golf at the end, this is doable in a fairly straightforward way by taking an algorithm that is always searching backwards, and getting rid of redundant work with a bit of caching.

@Spindoctor I added an explanation of how this solution can be reached starting with a straightforward solution and then adding caching, then getting smart about it.
